# developing android app using dreamweaver cs6

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, dreamweaver

Good day/night everyone. I am looking to go into mobile app development and made some research. I found out that you could use javascrpt, html5 and css to develop applications using phonegap. I also found out that dreamweaver supports phonegap and android sdk as plugins. My question now is, if I want to develop an android app in dreamweaver, am I to use the android native code or will I use html5, css and javascript that phonegaps uses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap only support for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. If you want add native functionality into hybrid app such as barcode scanner, camera or similar with that, you need to use cordova.exec.

Below is a list of phonegap plugin.

https://cordova.apache.org/

You can integrate native functionality into hybrid app also.

iOS: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/03/10/androidios-adding-native-functionality-to-hybrid-application-with-apache-cordova-plugin/

android: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/03/11/ios-adding-native-functionality-to-hybrid-application-with-apache-cordova-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver is web editing software, so you would use it for PhoneGap applications. If you want to do native development you will want to use Eclipse or Android Studio so you can compile the native code.